# How to import table and mail it using Excel?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to send a table via email using Excel VBA Code. The Code is working good but it does not allow me to send data in the form of the table. The structure of the sheet is as under.
[image]

I want to send the table to start with Sr. NO. I am using the below code which is working perfectly. But it sends only data in the form of values rather than a table.

```
    Sub Send_EmailFinal()
Dim xRg As Range
Dim I, J As Long
Dim xAddress As String
Dim xEmailBody As String
Dim xMailOut As Outlook.MailItem
Dim xOutApp As Outlook.Application
On Error Resume Next
xAddress = ActiveWindow.RangeSelection.Address
Set xRg = Range("H5:L32")
If xRg Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set xOutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set xMailOut = xOutApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)
For I = 1 To xRg.Rows.Count
For J = 1 To xRg.Columns.Count
xEmailBody = xEmailBody & " " & xRg.Cells(I, J).Value
Next
xEmailBody = xEmailBody & vbNewLine
Next
xEmailBody = "Hi" & vbLf & vbLf & " body of message you want to add" & vbLf & vbLf & xEmailBody & vbNewLine
With xMailOut
.subject = "Test"
.To = ""
.CC = ""
.subject = "Productivity Report"
.body = xEmailBody
.Display
'.Send
End With
Set xMailOut = Nothing
Set xOutApp = Nothing
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Please check it and guide me where I am doing wrong. Thanks

Comment: If you want to send the data in the form of a table then you need to use HTMLBody and create the appropriate HTML code.

Comment: https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s1/outlook/bmail2.htm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a function to build the [HTML](https://www.w3schools.com/html/) and the code in your sub can be minimal.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub Send_EmailFinal()
 
    Dim xMailOut As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim xOutApp As Outlook.Application
    Set xOutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set xMailOut = xOutApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)
    
    With xMailOut
        .BodyFormat = olFormatHTML
        .To = "###"
        .CC = ""
        .Subject = "Productivity Report"
        .HTMLBody = ToHTML(ActiveSheet.Range("H5:L32"))
        .Display
        '.Send
    End With
    Set xMailOut = Nothing
    Set xOutApp = Nothing
   
End Sub
 
Function ToHTML(rng As Range) As String
    Dim row As Range, cell As Range
    Dim n As Long, s As String

    s = "<p>Good Afternoon</p><p>Please see your productivity for lastweek, " & _
       "any questions or concerns please let me or Claudia know</p>"

    ' table header
    s = s & "<table border=""1"" width=""50%"" cellspacing=""0"" cellpadding=""3"" align=""center"">" & _
        "<tr align=""center"" bgcolor=""#CCCCCC"">"
    Set row = rng.Rows(1)
    For Each cell In row.cells
        s = s & "<th>" & cell & "</th>"
    Next
    s = s & "</tr>" & vbCrLf

    ' data
    For n = 2 To rng.Rows.Count
        Set row = rng.Rows(n)
        ' skip blank lines
        If Len(row.cells(1, 1)) > 0 Then
            s = s & "<tr align=""center"">"
            For Each cell In row.cells
                s = s & "<td>" & cell & "</td>"
            Next
            s = s & "</tr>" & vbCrLf
        End If
    Next
    ToHTML = s & "</table>"
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

For my limited applications, I am sending more basic emails that do not require the use of the Outlook object.
Try the following code that sends whatever is selected on your screen.
In a new workbook write something in several cells, select them then run the code (do not expect somebody to answer the from that email address).

```
Sub EmailSelectedRange()
    ActiveWorkbook.EnvelopeVisible = True
    With ActiveSheet.MailEnvelope
        .Item.To = "ThisIsAFakeEmailAddress@ThisIsAFakeEmailAddress.com"
        .Item.Subject = "This is the subject of the email"
        .Introduction = "This is a text in the email"
        .Item.Send
    End With
End Sub
```